# separador decimales en mysql

Tags: mysql

Tengo una tabla en `mysql` de productos donde el campo de precios tiene el siguiente formato con 3 decimales :

> 85.050 es un precio pero debería ser 85.050,00

Pero en mysql el separador decimal es el punto y no la coma, es decir si yo quiero poner el precio de ochenta y cinco mil cincuenta me pusiera

> 85.050 y me completara con 2 decimales ,00

Hay manera de poder hacer esto?

Actualmente la columna tiene 3 decimales decimal(10,3) que puse por error de entendimiento, como seria el cambio? estoy trabajando con phpmyadmin.

-
he hecho lo siguiente:

he creado una nuevo campo del tipo varchar desde el gestor llamada precios2

para hacer una copia del del campo precios

use la siguiente sentencia:

```
UPDATE productos SET precios2 = precios
```

y con eso ya tenia una copia, luego de eso me fui a la parte de estructura dentro de phpmyadmin y seleccione la opción cambiar sobre el campo precios2

esta vez lo cambie a decimal (10,2,'de_DE') y obtuve un error

solo deje 10,2 y se actualizó todo pero pensé que me completaría las 2 decimales mas.

```
lo que tenia | lo que quería | lo que obtuve
   85.050    |   85.050,00   |    85.05
```

Comment: Estás confundiendo almacenar el dato con visualizarlo. Deja el dato almacenado en la base de datos tal y como lo tenías, simplemente visualízalo utilizando `SELECT FORMAT(precio,2,'de_DE') FROM productos;`

Comment: entonces debo almacenar los datos asi como estan ( 85050 ), y al hacer el select para visualizarlo asi 85.050,00?

Comment: Sí, exacto, eso es... :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

En MySQL tienes una función específica para ello:

```
SELECT FORMAT(85050,2,'de_DE');
```

Y obtendrás algo así:

> 85.050,00

Échale un vistazo al [Manual de referencia](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_format) y recuerda incorporar algún intento a la pregunta para que podamos ayudarte.

Si sólo utilizas `SELECT FORMAT(85050,2);` obtendrás el resultado por defecto para `en_US` en la notación anglosajona (puntos en vez de coma, y viceversa):

> 85,050.00

Estás confundiendo almacenar el dato con visualizarlo. Deja el dato almacenado en la base de datos tal y como lo tenías (olvida el `UPDATE`), simplemente visualízalo utilizando

`SELECT FORMAT(precio,2,'de_DE') FROM productos;`

Comment: disculpa cual es la diferencia entre usar o no: `de_DE` pues en ambos casos retorna el resultado esperado

Comment: Te amplío la respuesta con ambos resultados, dame un minuto

Comment: gracias! pero tengo problemas al tratar de cambiar todos los campos, edite la pregunta

Comment: No te preocupes de cómo guardas el dato, la función FORMAT es sólo para visualizarlo al hacer un SELECT